# Сделать переменную php ссылкой и добавить ее в mailto

Tags: php

Имеется такой код:

```
        <dd><?=(!empty($customer_info['emails'])) ? implode(', ', $customer_info['emails']) : '<span class="muted">Не указано</span>';?></dd>
```

Выводит список имеющихся email адресов простым текстом.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы все адреса были ссылками. Таким образом:

```
<a href="mailto:name@email.ru">mailto:name@email.ru</a>
```

Очевидно что так не правильно:

```
<dd><a href=""><?=(!empty($customer_info['emails'])) ? implode(', ', $customer_info['emails'])</a>' : '<span class="muted">Не указано</span>';?></dd>
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Что пробовали, что не получилось? Как бы сам собой напрашивается цикл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сначала преобразовать все имейлы в ссылки.

```
<?php
  $to_mail = function( $addr ){ return "<a href='mailto:$addr'>$addr</a>"; };
  $all_emails = array_map( $to_mail, $customer_info['emails'] ?? [] );
  //это можно и не выносить отдельно, но тогда совсем не читабельно.
  // "??" из php7 (null coalesce operator)
?>
<dd>
    <?php if( $all_emails ): ?>
       <?= implode(', ', $all_emails ); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
       <span class="muted">Не указано</span>'
    <?php endif; ?>
</dd>
```

Comment: спасибо! сделала немного по-другому: `<?php
  $to_mail = function( $addr ){ return "<a href='mailto:$addr'>$addr</a>"; };
  $all_emails = array_map( $to_mail, Utils::is($customer_info['emails'], []));
  ?>`

Comment: зачем $to_mail то...

Comment: Просто чтоб разбить слишком длинную строку, в принципе можно всё запихнуть в `array_map` или `implode`.

Comment: @Deadooshka Или вам само название переменной не нравится? Согласен, оно не особо удачно выбрано, по смыслу больше подойдет `$to_email_anchor` или `$convert_to_email_anchor`.